# Google Custom Search API: The billing information added but still not going beyond the free query limit

Tags: google-app-engine, search, google-api, search-engine, google-custom-search

I have activated billing, and added the information, but it's still not going beyond the free query limit; it says:

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Daily Limit Exceeded",
    "reason" : "dailyLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Daily Limit Exceeded"
}
```

I also tried creating a new API, but it didn't help. Anyone has any idea?

Here is the code I use:

```
Builder builder = new Customsearch.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), null);
builder.setApplicationName("Search Test");
builder.setCustomsearchRequestInitializer(new CustomsearchRequestInitializer() {
    @Override
    protected void initializeCustomsearchRequest(CustomsearchRequest<?> request) throws IOException {

        request.setKey("???");  
        request.set("cx", "013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a");
        request.set("start", start); 
    }
});
Customsearch customsearch = builder.build();
Search searchResult = customsearch.cse().list(searchTerm).execute();


System.out.println("About " + searchResult.getSearchInformation().getTotalResults() + " results available");
List<Result> items = searchResult.getItems();
```

In the console, I tried to increase the quota manually, but it doesn't work. Here is what I clicked on: 
[image]

And change the value: 
[image]

And after ok everything looks fine: 
[image]

But after refreshing the page, everything reverts back (quota 0, for today; just like the first image).

Note that I have added the billing information: 
[image]

Update: Seems like there is a bug with the new console. I changed the quota from the old console and it worked!

Comment: You will need to post the code you are using for authentication. If you aren't sending it correctly then you are going to get the dailylimit.

Comment: posted the code here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new console is buggy. As I explained in the question, I was not able to increase the quota. Instead I used the old console and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. wait for a few minutes
2. make sure you have adjusted the daily budget in google developer console -> compute -> appengine -> settings -> application settings. the default was 0 which is same as free.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added the code. Also, the address that you gave is for the new console or the old one? It shows me the new console, and inside that I couldn't find the address you are giving me.

Comment: Also, by "wait for a few minutes" you mean between every query?